# CSS3 - Fade between 'background-position' of a sprite image

Tags: css, image, sprite, fade, background-position

I want to fade between 'background-position' of a sprite image **only with CSS**. I found a lot o tutorials but I didn't found something simple like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CSS3 - Fade between 'background-position' of a sprite image</title>
<style type="text/css">
div{
    width:  120px;
    height: 60px;

    background-image:       url('sprite.jpg');
    background-repeat:      no-repeat;
    background-position:    0   0;

}
div:hover{
    background-position:    0   -60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't setup any fades. You can do it either with javascript or css3 animations, depending on how many browsers you wish to support.

Comment: This is a nice article on the topic https://css-tricks.com/fade-image-within-sprite/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks anyway.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CSS3 - Fade between 'background-position' of a sprite image</title>
<style type="text/css">
#button{
    float:                  left;
    background-image:       url('sprite.jpg');
    background-position:    0 -60px;
    background-repeat:      no-repeat;

    width:              120px;
    height:             60px;
}
#button a{
    background-image:       url('sprite.jpg');
    background-position:    0 0;
    background-repeat:      no-repeat;

    width:              120px;
    height:             60px;

    display:            block; 
    text-indent:        -9999px; 

    transition:         opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:    opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:      opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#button a:hover, 
#button a:focus{ 
    opacity:            0; 
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="button"><a href="#"></a></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

so basically, you need to perform two things upon `:hover`

1. `background-position` change
2. `fadein` effect

CSS3 transition won't be useful in this case. 
You can use CSS3 animation property.

animation property accepts `name` of the animation and duration. Multiple animation names can be provided separated by comma.

you need to define these animation names.They can be any string of your choice,  but you need to define them. 
so consider this css:

```
div:hover{
   animation: fadein 10s, bp 0.5s;
   -moz-animation: fadein 10s, bp 0.5s; /* Firefox */
   -webkit-animation: fadein 10s, bp 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-animation: fadein 10s, bp 0.5s; 
    background-position:0 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bp { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        background-position:-200px 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position:0 0;
    }
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BqcWu/4/), for complete browser supported animation

NOTE: it won't work in IE<9 for sure! and it might in IE9(not sure).

Comment: this is a slide, not a fading between a background-position of a sprite

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CSS3 Animation` with `@keyframes`

```
div:hover{
  animation: logo 2s 0 linear;
}
@keyframes logo{
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  5%   { opacity: 0; }
  50%  { background-position: 0 -60px; opacity: 0; }
  100% { background-position: 0 -60px; opacity: 1; }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8W9S/

Of course, now you have to adjust the times and effect you want to implement.

Hope it's helps or point you in right direction.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
div{
    width:  120px;
    height: 60px;

    background-image: url('sprite.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0   0;
    transition: background-position 1s ease;

}
```

And don't forget the optional vendor prefixes

**Edit:**

I've noticed you need fade. You try to similar solution like this:

```
div{
    background: url(foo.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    transition: background: 1s ease;
}

div:hover{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

*I can't try this, coz' im from mobile.*

Comment: This will slide the bg image, rather than fade it in adn out.

Comment: This isn't fade between position of a sprite image.

Comment: The `div` is transparent and this will show a white page, and on hover will fade to black.... I don't understand what you tried.